# puppet: Why is the file resource not created?

Tags: puppet

I have the following code on a manifest:

```
  $shutdown_script = '/etc/init.d/puppet-report-shutdown'                                                                                                       
  file { 'shutdown-script':                                                                                                                                     
    ensure => present,                                                                                                                                          
    path   => $shutdown_script,                                                                                                                                 
    owner  => 'root',                                                                                                                                           
    group  => 'root',                                                                                                                                           
    mode   => '0755',                                                                                                                                           
    source => 'puppet:///modules/puppet_agent/puppet-report-shutdown.sh'                                                                                        
  }                                                                                                                                                             

  exec { 'chkconfig':                                                                                                                                           
    command => "chkconfig --add ${shutdown_script}",                                                                                                            
    require => File['shutdown-script']                                                                                                                          
  }
```

The exec code is failing, because it cannot find the script:

```
`Error: Failed to apply catalog: Validation of Exec[chkconfig] failed: 'chkconfig --add /etc/init.d/puppet-report-shutdown' is not qualified and no path was specified. Please qualify the command or specify a path. at /etc/puppet/environments/dev02/modules/puppet_agent/manifests/init.pp:50
```

The file resource is not being created, but I can't find why. I tried running the agent with `--debug`, but there's nothing useful there (to the best of my knoledge, at least):

```
Debug: /File[shutdown-script]/seluser: Found seluser default 'system_u' for /etc/init.d/puppet-report-shutdown
Debug: /File[shutdown-script]/selrole: Found selrole default 'object_r' for /etc/init.d/puppet-report-shutdown
Debug: /File[shutdown-script]/seltype: Found seltype default 'initrc_exec_t' for /etc/init.d/puppet-report-shutdown
Debug: /File[shutdown-script]/selrange: Found selrange default 's0' for /etc/init.d/puppet-report-shutdown
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are actually a few problems here, but let us go through them sequentially.

1. `ensure => file`

The `file` resource should be specifying an `ensure` of `file` instead of present. That instructs Puppet more specifically as to what the type and content of the `file` on the node should be:

```
file { 'shutdown-script':                                                                                                                                     
  ensure => file,                                                                                                                                          
  path   => $shutdown_script,                                                                                                                                 
  owner  => 'root',                                                                                                                                           
  group  => 'root',                                                                                                                                           
  mode   => '0755',                                                                                                                                           
  source => 'puppet:///modules/puppet_agent/puppet-report-shutdown.sh'                                                                                        
}
```

2. `command => "/sbin/chkconfig --add ${shutdown_script}"`

The `exec` resource either requires a full path to the command, or you can specify lookup paths with the `path` attribute. In this case, the easiest solution is to provide the full path:

```
exec { 'chkconfig':                                                                                                                                           
  command => "/sbin/chkconfig --add ${shutdown_script}",                                                                                                            
  require => File['shutdown-script']                                                                                                                          
}
```

This is actually your root cause here. The file is not being created because the Puppet agent is never actually applying your catalog because you have a compilation error:

> Error: Failed to apply catalog: Validation of Exec[chkconfig] failed: 'chkconfig --add /etc/init.d/puppet-report-shutdown' is not qualified and no path was specified. Please qualify the command or specify a path. at /etc/puppet/environments/dev02/modules/puppet_agent/manifests/init.pp:50

3. `service`

Instead of using `exec` to add the service, you can add and enable it with the `enable` attribute in the `service` resource. I would also recommend changing the `require` metaparameter to `subscribe`, because otherwise your changes to the service script will not be picked up by the system's service manager. With `subscribe`, Puppet will instruct the system to recognize and reconfigure the service if the script changes. This is also a problem with your current `exec` resource.

```
service { 'puppet-report-shutdown':
  enable    => true,
  subscribe => File['shutdown-script'],
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That was a really useful answer. Although the root cause was the lookup path, as you and @SamK suggested, I have also edited the manifest to follow your recommendations. I'm still a puppet newbie, so a bit of 'good practice' advice is always appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The error message clearly states the issue.

Puppet needs the command to be "[*either fully qualified or a search path for the command must be provided*](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/types/exec.html#exec-attribute-command)".

Either fully qualify your command like this:

```
command => "/usr/sbin/chkconfig --add ${shutdown_script}",
```

or specify some path like this (usually when you're not sure where the command lies):

```
path => [ '/bin', '/sbin', '/usr/bin', '/usr/sbin' ],
```